# Deleting local branch named origin/xyz without deleting remote branch with same name xyz in Git?

Tags: git, github

I have 2 **local** branches named `origin/QAD-1649` and `QAD-1649`, and a **remote** branch with same name `QAD-1649`. I want to delete the **local** branch named `origin/QAD-1649` without deleting the **remote** branch so that I can continue working on the **local** branch `QAD-1649` which should track **remote** branch `origin/QAD-1649`.

The **local** branch `QAD-1649` currently tracks some another branch `origin/compare` which is in *forked* main project repository. I am trying to update it to `origin/QAD-1649` in my *main* project repository. How can I achieve this without losing my **remote** branch `QAD-1649`?

Comment: To be clear, `git branch` lists both `origin/QAD-1649` and `QAD-1649`?

Comment: yes. it list out both branches.

Answer (score 3):

`git branch -d` only deletes local branches. So `git branch -d origin/QAD-1649`.

Comment: so local QAD-1649 should track origin/QAD-1649 rather than some different which is already deleted in remote repo??

Comment: @I_am_Vits `git branch -u origin/QAD-1649 QAD-1649`.